# Using boost.signals2 how do I connect dynamically allocated objects to a signal

Tags: c++, boost, boost-signals2

I have a class named `Candidate` containing a function named `DataUpdate()`. I intend to dynamically create many instances of Candidate and have each instance connect it's function `DataUpdate()` as a slot to a `boost.signals2` signal; in readiness to receive signals.

The code I have developed below is giving the error:

> Error 2 error C2276: '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression

I'm unsure of the correct code to achieve the desired result. The problem seems to lie in in dereferencing the pointer `candidateInstance` to get the address of the instance's `DataUpdate()` function to pass to `signal.connect()`.  Is anyone please able to advise the correct approach?

```
Candidate *candidateInstance;

//INSTANTIATE CANDIDATE INSTANCE
++DataStream::ID;//increment static variable
candidatesVector.push_back(candidateInstance = new Candidate(ID));

//CONNECT DATAUPDATE() OF CANDIDATE INSTANCE
signal.connect( &((*candidateInstance).DataUpdate) );

//FIRE SIGNAL
signal(BarNumber(), DateTime(), Open(), High(), Low(), Close());
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `bind` to create wrapper for member function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

#include <boost/signals2.hpp>

class Foo
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "I'm foo() from Foo, this == " << this << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto foo_ptr = std::make_shared<Foo>();

    boost::signals2::signal<void()> sig;

    sig.connect(std::bind(&Foo::foo, foo_ptr));

    sig();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So I tried using the format you suggested but this line; signal.connect(std::bind(std::mem_fn(&Candidate::DataUpdate), candidateInstance.get())); gives the error; Error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 6 arguments.  Any thoughts on how to fix it? Thanks. @soon

Comment: Looks like your function has more arguments than function represented in my answer. In this case you should use [placeholders](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders).

Comment: `bind` doesn't require `mem_fn` and can be bound to `shared_ptr`: `bind(&Foo::foo, foo_ptr);`

Comment: @soon Thanks for putting me on the right track, got code to compile and run like so:                                                                                                        `//INSTANTIATE CANDIDATE INSTANCE
++DataStream::ID;//increment static variable to give unique ID no.
Candidate* candidateInstance = new Candidate(ID, iDataNumber);
    
//CONNECT DATAUPDATE() OF CANDIDATE INSTANCE
signal.connect(bind(&Candidate::DataUpdate, candidateInstance, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7));

//FIRE SIGNAL
signal(iDataNumber, BarNumber(), DateTime(), Open(), High(), Low(), Close());`